# Update database through TableAdapter

Tags: c#, tableadapter

I'm using the table adapter in C# where I created a DataGridView. When I double click a row, I am displaying all the cells in the row in textboxes in a different Form. After I edit the textboxes and click my save button, I would like to take the values from the textboxes and replace them in the database. I can see the changes on the DataGrid, however I am not able to save them in the database.

```
private void InventoryData_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

{
   //make new form and display them there
   ViewInventoryItem ViewItem = new ViewInventoryItem();

   ViewItem.textBox1.Text = this.InventoryData.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   ViewItem.textBox2.Text = this.InventoryData.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
   ViewItem.textBox3.Text = this.InventoryData.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
   ViewItem.ShowDialog();

   if (ViewItem.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
   {
       //save button was pressed
       this.InventoryData.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = ViewItem.textBox1.Text;
       this.InventoryData.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = ViewItem.textBox2.Text;
       this.InventoryData.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value = ViewItem.textBox3.Text;

       this.Validate();
       this.InventoryData.EndEdit();                 
       this.booksTableAdapter.Update(this.InventoryDataSet.Books);   
   }
             
}
```

Comment: Have you set an UpdateCommand on the adapter?

Comment: After doing a try catch on the last 3 lines, I am getting exceptionon .Update that I don't have a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows. I thought this was handled automatically, not sure what I need to add to make it work.

Comment: No, it is not automatic. When you created your TableAdapter you should have gone through a wizard where you set the SelectCommand. You should have been able to set the UpdateCommand (and Insert, and Delete) in the wizard too. Its been a long time since I used that tech, but I think you can open the wizard at any time and set those things.

Comment: ok, I see now that in my Wizard I have only Select and Insert Queries set properly. The Update ones weren't properly generated due to errors. Will fix them and try again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. In the Dataset the Table had only Fill and Get Data. Even after selecting the Wizard to add the other statements it was failing. After adding the UpdateQuery manually, the code works without issues. Thank you Crowcoder for pointing me in the right direction.